# Generic Method to Create Multiple Fragments

Tags: java, android, generics, android-fragments

I want to write a method that creates multiple fragments for me and I am not sure how to do this.  After a few attempts I got more confused.

Here is how I typically and creating two fragments

```
private void createFragDog(Animals animals) {
    DogFragment frag = DogFragment.newInstance(ArrayList<Dogs> animals.getDogs());
    ...    
    *frag.(do fragment manager stuff and commit())*
    ...
}
```

Second call to create fragment

```
private void createFragCat(Animals animals) {
    CatFragment frag = CatFragment.newInstance(ArrayList<Cats> animals.getCats());
    ...    
    *frag.(do fragment manager stuff and commit())*
    ...
}
```

Being that the newInstance method is static I can't seem to figure out how to make a generic method and just pass in the class types. Also the object passed into newInstance is not always an array. Here is my attempt:

```
private <T,E> void animalFragments(Class<T> frag, Class<E> animalType, Object obj){
    if (obj == null) return;
    if (obj instanceof List<?>) {
        if (((List<E>)obj).isEmpty()) return;
    }

    try {
        T fragment = (T) frag.newInstance();
        ?? Not sure what to do now or how to call up method that is static but specific to both.

    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did it this way hope this helps.

```
private <T,E> void animalFragments(Class<T> frag, Object obj){
    Method m = null;
    try {
        m = frag.newInstance().getClass().getDeclaredMethod("newInstance", obj.getClass());
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (m != null) {
        T fragment = null;
        try {
            fragment = (T) m.invoke(null, obj);

            if (fragment != null) {
                FragmentTransaction trans = this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                trans.add(R.id.ll_fragments_container, (Fragment) fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName());
                trans.commit();
                return true;
            }
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```